# convert same labels over multiple columns in a data frame to numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe as:

```
df =
    A     B     C    D      E
   ---   ---   ---  ---    ---
0  J969  I279  D65   -1    -1
1  C56   A419  I279  C221  -1
2  R068  D65   N009  -1    -1
3  C56  T107  J969  R068  N009
```

I need to be able to encode the labels in all of the columns. If a label matches another label (e.g column A row 0 and column C row 3) anywhere in the dataframe they must be encoded to the same number. As such:

```
    A     B     C    D      E
   ---   ---   ---  ---    ---
0   0     3     7    -1     -1
1   1     2     6    15     -1
2   4     7     10   -1     -1
3   1     8     0     4     10
```

I have tried `pandas.factorize`, `pandas.Categorize`, Scikit-learn `LabelEncoder` from examples on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = {d: i for i, d in enumerate(pd.unique(df.as_matrix().flatten()))}
new_df = pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].map(m) for c in df.columns})
```

- `m` is a map mapping the unique elements in the DataFrame to indices, according to some arbitrary order.
- The dictionary comprehensio goes over columns, and translates each one according to the map.